# How to add margin between Bootstrap cards without triggering flex-wrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox, bootstrap-5

I'm using Bootstrap cards and I want to separate them by a 2px margin.

Nonetheless, when I apply it (either with Bootstrap's margin classes or directly on my stylesheet) flex-wrap triggers and a card goes one row down.

How could I deal with this behavior?

Should I give a max-width to the cards?

```css
.dark-theme body,
.dark-theme .card {
  background-color: #121212;
  color: #ffffffa6;
}

.dark-theme section.card {
  background-color: #464646;
}

.card {
  border-width: 0;
  margin: 3px;
}

main {
  padding: 100px;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

h2,
.card {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.dark-theme .btn {
  background-color: salmon;
  border-color: salmon;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<div class="highlights row">
  <section class="card col-md-6 col-lg-4">
    <h3>Where does it come from?</h3>
    <p>
      orem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.
    </p>
    <p>orem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</p>
    <a href="#" class="card__btn btn btn-info">when an unknown</a>
  </section>

  <section class="card col-md-6 col-lg-4">
    <h3>Where does it come from?</h3>
    <p>
      orem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.
    </p>
    <p>
      orem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.
    </p>
    <a href="#" class="card__btn btn btn-info">
                  when an unknown
                </a>
  </section>

  <section class="card col-md-6 col-lg-4">
    <h3>Where does it come from?</h3>
    <p>
      orem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s
    </p>
    <p>orem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</p>
    <a href="#" class="card__btn btn btn-info">
                  when an unknown
                </a>
  </section>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First and foremost, remove any margins set on Bootstrap classes. Bootstrap is intended to not need to add spacing/sizing, as it is built into the classes.

I re-worked your structure quite a bit. Mostly to try to structure the elements as Bootstrap recommends. With that being said, don't nest each card in sections. Instead, nest them in divs. [The `<section>` tag defines a section in a document.](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_section.asp) & if I am not mistaken, the three cards aligned in a row qualify as a section. I nested all three cards in one section and called it the `highlights` class you already had.

`col`'s function as a method of reserving space for certain content. So with a three-card setup, you should use `col-4`. The largest col is `col-12`, which spans the full width of the screen. 12/4 = 3. Then you can use `sm` `lg` and `md` for responsiveness on media screens. The above example creates three equal-width columns on small, medium, large, and extra-large devices using the predefined grid classes. Those columns are centered on the page with the `row` parent.

With this being said, the main reason your code was not working as intended is the additional CSS margins and that the `cards` should be nested in the `col`'s. Lastly, the misuse of column sizing as mentioned previously.

I'd suggest brushing up on the [Bootstrap Grid System](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/). You can build a fully responsive site with little knowledge in CSS if you know Bootstrap.

```css
.dark-theme body,
.dark-theme .card {
  background-color: #121212;
  color: #ffffffa6;
}

.dark-theme section.card {
  background-color: #464646;
}

.card {
  border-width: 0;
}

main {
  padding: 100px;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

.dark-theme .btn {
  background-color: salmon;
  border-color: salmon;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<section class="highlights">
  <div class="row w-100 m-0 justify-content-center">

    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
      <div class="card w-100">
        <h3>Where does it come from?</h3>
        <p>
          orem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.
        </p>
        <p>orem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</p>
        <a href="#" class="card__btn btn btn-info">when an unknown</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
      <div class="card w-100">
        <h3>Where does it come from?</h3>
        <p>
          orem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.
        </p>
        <p>
          orem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.
        </p>
        <a href="#" class="card__btn btn btn-info">
      when an unknown
      </a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
      <div class="card w-100">
        <h3>Where does it come from?</h3>
        <p>
          orem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s
        </p>
        <p>orem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</p>
        <a href="#" class="card__btn btn btn-info">
    when an unknown
    </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here, You can used [Gutters](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/layout/gutters/#row-columns-gutters) class in the Bootstrap grid system.

**Gutters are the gaps between column content, created by horizontal padding.** We set padding-right and padding-left on each column, and use negative margin to offset that at the start and end of each row to align content.

You can use `g-1`, `g-2`, `g-3`, `g-4`, and `g-5` in row according to your needs.

```css
.dark-theme body, .dark-theme .card {background-color: #121212; color: #ffffffa6;}
.dark-theme section.card {background-color: #464646;}
.card {border-width: 0;}
main {padding: 100px;}
h1 {text-align: center;}
.dark-theme .btn {background-color: salmon;border-color: salmon;}
```

```html
<head>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<section class="highlights">
  <div class="row justify-content-center g-1">

    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
      <div class="card">
        <h3>Where does it come from?</h3>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.</p>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</p>
        <a href="#" class="card__btn btn btn-info">when an unknown</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
      <div class="card">
        <h3>Where does it come from?</h3>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.</p>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.</p><a href="#" class="card__btn btn btn-info">when an unknown</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
      <div class="card">
        <h3>Where does it come from?</h3>
        <p>orem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</p><p>orem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</p>
<a href="#" class="card__btn btn btn-info">when an unknown</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```